# Objective-C File Copy Multithreading?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, file-copying

I am trying to write a program using Objective-C/XCode that backs up one directory (source dir) into another (dest dir).

When I test the program on a small directory on my local machine, it works as expected. But when I try a large directory, or anything over a network, the program beachballs. I know that threading is the answer. Given the following code one can tell I have been fiddling with various methods to do this. Can anyone help out? I can't seem to get this working properly.
Here is the code/method in question:

```
- (void)doSync:(NSString *)sURL {
bStopCopy = NO;
NSString *sSource = [[pcSource URL] path];
NSString *sDestination = [[pcDestination URL] path];
NSString *sSourcePath = [sSource stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString *sDestinationPath = [sDestination stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString *sSourceFile;
NSString *sDestinationFile;
NSString* file;
NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:sURL];

while ((file = [enumerator nextObject]) && (bStopCopy == NO)) {
    [btMainWindowStopQuitButton setTitle: @"Stop..."];
    [btMainWindowStopQuitButton setTag:1];
    bCopyInProgress = YES;
    __block NSError *eErrorMessage;
    sSourceFile = [sSourcePath stringByAppendingString:file];
    sDestinationFile = [sDestinationPath stringByAppendingString:file];
    // check if it's a directory & exists at destination
    BOOL isDirectory = NO;
    BOOL isFileExistingAtDestination = NO;
    __block BOOL isThereAnError = NO;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",sURL,file]
                                         isDirectory: &isDirectory];
    isFileExistingAtDestination = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: sDestinationFile];

    if (!isDirectory) {
        if (!isFileExistingAtDestination) {
            //                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            //                    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sSourceFile toPath:sDestinationFile error: &eErrorMessage]) {
            //                        NSLog(@"File Copy Error: %@", eErrorMessage);
            //                        isThereAnError = YES;
            //                    }
            //                });

            //[oqFileCopy addOperationWithBlock:^{
            dispatch_queue_t copyQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Copy File", NULL);
            dispatch_async(copyQueue, ^{
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sSourceFile toPath:sDestinationFile error: &eErrorMessage]) {
                    NSLog(@"File Copy Error: %@", eErrorMessage);
                    isThereAnError = YES;
                }
            //[oqMain addOperationWithBlock:^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    llFileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: sDestinationFile error: Nil] fileSize];
                    [[[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] mutableString] setString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nCopied to: %@ (%qu bytes)", [[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] string], sDestinationFile, llFileSize]];
                    NSRange endPoint = NSMakeRange ([[tvDialogueLabel string] length], 0);
                    [tvDialogueLabel scrollRangeToVisible: endPoint];
                    llTotalFileSize = llTotalFileSize + llFileSize;
                });
            });
            //                NSLog(@"%@", sSourceFile);
            //                NSLog(@"%@", sDestinationFile);
        } else if (isFileExistingAtDestination) {
            [[[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] mutableString] setString:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nFile: %@ | Already Synced.", [[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] string], sDestinationFile]];
            NSRange endPoint = NSMakeRange ([[tvDialogueLabel string] length], 0);
            [tvDialogueLabel scrollRangeToVisible: endPoint];
        }
    }
    else if (isDirectory) {
        if (!isFileExistingAtDestination) {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:sDestinationFile withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error: &eErrorMessage]){
                NSLog(@"Directory Create Failed: %@", eErrorMessage);
                isThereAnError = YES;
            }
            [[[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] mutableString] setString:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nCreated Directory: %@", [[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] string], sDestinationFile]];
            NSRange endPoint = NSMakeRange ([[tvDialogueLabel string] length], 0);
            [tvDialogueLabel scrollRangeToVisible: endPoint];
            //                NSLog(@"%@", sSourceFile);
            //                NSLog(@"%@", sDestinationFile);
        } else if (isFileExistingAtDestination) {
            [[[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] mutableString] setString:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nDirectory: %@ | Already Exists.", [[tvDialogueLabel textStorage] string], sDestinationFile]];
            NSRange endPoint = NSMakeRange ([[tvDialogueLabel string] length], 0);
            [tvDialogueLabel scrollRangeToVisible: endPoint];
        }
        [self doSync: file];
    }

    if (isThereAnError) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error!");
        //[_wDialogue setTitle: @"Error while syncing..."];
        break;
    }
    //        NSLog(@"%@", @"==================================================");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to remove all the block code from your method, and simply make your call to doSync: using performSelectorInBackground:withObject:. For example:

```
[foo performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSync:) withObject:myURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way of doing this, if you're using OSX 10.6 and up, would be to throw all this code to Grand Central Dispatch. The `while` loop is what needs to be on a different thread, that's the one that's holding up the main thread. By wrapping the whole thing into a `dispatch_async()`, you're moving that `while` loop on a different thread as well.

```
- (void)doSync:(NSString *)sURL {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        // your doSync code goes here
    });
}
```